# php time 2 hours wrong for only 50% some users

Tags: php

I am having huge issues with php time.

For some reason it shows a different time (by 2 hours) to some users and the correct time to other users.

The code is H:i:s d-M-y T when I view the page in a browser from my PC it tells me its 11am when infact its 9am, when I check via a browser using one my RDP's I get the correct time.

Both PC's are in the country (uk) both PC's have the same system time etc.

Tried setting the timezone default, but no matter what I do the server still shows some users the correct time, and other users the time 2 hour forward, any ideas?

the code is `echo gmdate("H:i:s d-M-y T");`

```
<?php echo gmdate("H:i:s d-M-y T"); ?>
```

Comment: PHP is server-side programming, so any time displayed by it should be same.

Comment: a) Need code ;) b) @ChristianNikkanen if users have the ability to select their own timezone, the information would probably be saved in the DB and then loaded when serving content to each user. My guess is this is happening because of incorrect UI to time zone code mapping. This brings me back to my point (a) that we need code!

Comment: <?php


echo gmdate("H:i:s d-M-y T");

?>

Comment: I am aware that php is server side, and thats whats confusing me, because how can the server have 2 times? one correct and one two hours in front lol

Comment: current test page is http://funkyred.com/t.php

Comment: we need the code, @user1797802. can't see it on the web server.

Comment: posted the code, its just one line echo gmdate("H:i:s d-M-y T");

Comment: @user1797802 Is this managed hosting or a dedicated machine? If managed, you may see responses from two differerent machines.

Comment: web hosting from 123 reg, dedicated

Comment: It's showing 10:10 for me which is correct. Are you sure this isn't a caching issue of some sort? It seems very unlikely that the server is causing this

Comment: Is it not correcting for local time perhaps?

Comment: ip removed  4-Nov-12    10:09:18    
ip removed  4-Nov-12    10:09:18    
ip removed  4-Nov-12    10:09:22    
ip removed  4-Nov-12    08:09:54    
ip removed  4-Nov-12    08:10:01

Comment: as you can see from above its showing some users correct time, and others incorrect

Comment: I have 4000 lines just like that, 50% correct time 50% 2 hours incorrect

Comment: Make sure you're useing `setlocale` correctly, read more http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: @Morgan that won't matter for GMT time though.

Comment: This looks really crazy. I don't see how `gmdate()` could be the culprit here. Could it be the system clock? Weird.

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention, been using this code for logging for the last 8 months with no problems at all, only since the time change as this error started occurring.

Comment: a comment from the php docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php#92465 `Greenwich Mean Time has no "Summer Time" or "Daylight Saving Time" so depending on the season of the year these statements may produce the same or different output.`

Comment: @user1797802 try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php#71147, if it works, make a function of it (y)

Comment: even if I simply use echo time(); there is still a 2 hour difference.

Comment: @user1797802 Is the text with `ip removed` above from the access log?

Comment: no, I have a simple code that logs my page hits, it records IP (for unique reasons) the time and date, the idea is so I can find my peak audience times, the time code is the one posted and all it does is record it to a text document for review later.

Comment: @user1797802 from what i see, there are 50% of the users with the right timing, and the others return -2h of the actual time ?

Comment: @user1797802 Do the access logs have the same varying times or are they all in the correct GMT time?

Comment: ok I have finally found the issue, I created a phpinfo file, when I looked on it on my browser, then looked at it from another pc I got 2 different build dates, it would appear I am shared hosting and users are getting different php.ini settings, anyway to fix this?

Comment: @user1797802 If you're on shared hosting, you should talk to the hoster first. You can fix the time issue using a common header for all files that sets the time zone offset, but getting different versions may of course cause other problems.

Comment: thank you to everyone for the help, I have messaged my provider with the issue and will hopefully get them to fix it, in the mean time is there anyway to force the web server to read from only one php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around, let me explain this: There are users who get the right time, others get -2h. If we log the last time in a file, and next time a user opens the page, we check if $now is smaller than $last_time, if it is, we add 2 hours ! Let me explain this with numbers, User1 visited the page, and it returns the right hour, let's say 11AM. User2 opens the page, and it return 9AM, obviously we can't return in the time, so we add 2 hours !

Here the code:

```
<?php
$last_time = file_get_contents("file.txt"); // a file where the last time has been saved
$now = strtotime(gmdate("H:i:s d-M-y T")); // Now !
if($now < $last_time){
    $now += 7200; // add 2 hours !
}
file_put_contents("file.txt", $now);
echo gmdate("H:i:s d-M-y T", $now);
?>
```

Hope this was helpful !